# In WPF how do I specify the path to a file nested in a Directory using XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, file, path

I am trying to do this...

```
<Image x:Name="imgGroupImage" Source="Images\unlock.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
```

But I get this error...

> Cannot convert string 'Images\unlock.png' in attribute 'Source' to object of type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'. Cannot locate resource 'forms/images/unlock.png'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.HierarchicalDataTemplate' in markup file 'Fuse;component/forms/mainwindow.xaml' Line 273 Position 51.

As you can see, my form that includes this XAML is in a folder named Forms. My Images are in a folder named Images. How do I map from Forms to Images?

I tried `Source="..Images\unlock.png"` which does not work in WPF.

Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try slashes rather than backslashes, and use an absolute path by leading with a slash:

```
Source="/Images/unlock.png"
```

That generally works for me.

Failing that, take a look at [Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).

Comment: The Pack URI link is not working for me. This is an equivalent:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 5):

1. Add your image to the Project in VS
2. Right click on that image **unlock.png**
3. Go to Context menu /Properties
4. Change Build Action to Resource

Thats it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the source to a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx)?

```
<Image x:Name="imgGroupImage" Margin="0,0,5,0"  >
   <Image.Source>
      <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/unlock.png" />
   </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

I believe the default type of `Uri` for `UriSource` is a relative `Uri`, which works off the application's base class.  You might find you can configure the `BitmapSource` a bit easier than trying to find the exact way you have to enter the file path in the `Source` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use resource located in folder different that the one where your XAML is, do this:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/image.png"/>
```

Where **Resources** is name of directory which you want to use resources from and **image.png is** name of image to display. Answer found thanks to @matt-hamilton and @brian-hinchey and their mention of Pack URI.
Works perfectly with your own Converters. You just have to return string matching schema above.