# Pack URI and path not resolving image in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, pack-uri

I have the following directory structure

```
Project
\Images
 +view.png
control.xaml
```

and in the control I have a button defined by the following XAML:

```
<Button Click="Search"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="0,5,5, 0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/images/view.png"
                   Width="16"
                   Height="16"
                   ToolTip="Search"
                   Cursor="Hand"
                   Opacity="0.8" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

However, neither this pack URI method nor the "/images/view.png" is working. As I understand it, this is the same issue [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278943/in-wpf-how-do-i-specify-the-path-to-a-file-nested-in-a-directory-using-xaml) raises. However, I get the same error. The confusing thing is that in designer in Visual Studio 2008, the image renders correctly, but on the call to the InitializeComponent() call, I get:

> Cannot convert string 'pack://application:,,,/images/view.png' in attribute 'Source' to object of type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'. Cannot locate resource 'images/view.png'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate' in markup file 'RecapSpecEditControl;component/modaltreadgroupdatadialog.xaml' Line 61 Position 40.

I thought that maybe there was a namespace that I had to declare but according to the [msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) I believe I don't have to do anything like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually got this to work, but had to set my source to `/ProjectName;component/images/view.png` Because I have the ProjectName as a referenced assembly this is then the same as the Path: portion at the msdn page that I referenced in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Set the Build Action for 'view.png' to Resource instead of Content and this problem should go away.  I was able to reproduce your problem this way and it works correctly when set as a Resource.

Comment: I thought you might be on to something, but my build action on the image is already set to resource. What about the Copy to Output directory, what do you have that set as?

Comment: 'Do not copy'.  Interesting.  I thought for sure that was it, as it displayed in the designer and gave me the exact same error at runtime when I had it building as Content.

Comment: Your answer made total sense, and I was certain that I would see that my build action was wrong.

Comment: Found the solution, but yours is definitely worth noting as a possible answer under the right circumstances as you demonstrated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction. Similar issue as OP but I had my Build Action to 'Embedded Resource' switching to 'Resource' corrected it.

Answer (score -3):

> Xaml.VB

Call the Image from Application folder and Design Page

```
Private Sub LoadImages()
        Dim strUri As String
        strUri = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory() & "\NavigationImages\settingsicon.png"
        Image2.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri(strUri))
    End Sub
```

Page load in Xaml.VB

`Call LoadImages()`

Xaml Design Page

```
Image Name="Image2"Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
```