# Image don't display in Modern UI For WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I'm developing a Modern UI app for WPF c#. The problem is the Image displays only in mode design. When I execute the app, it doesn't show.
I added "pack://siteoforigin:,,," but it doesn't work.
Anyone can  help me please!

Code:

```
Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Image/back1.png"
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874705/pack-uri-and-path-not-resolving-image-in-wpf)?

Comment: @MikeChristensen we should have something like a search bar, or maybe a search engine, that can help people find answers to questions ...

Comment: @Noctis - You should invent that and get rich.

Comment: string path = "pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Image/back1.png"  and see if the path is correct. And check the img is Resource.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF image resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources)

Comment: In Modern UI I can not set image programmatically like .Source = BitmapFrame.Create(...

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer but it could help someone else. Please click on the image and in the properties section, under advance options select build action as Resource. Hope it will work.[image]